# Create React App with Web Audio Api doesn't insert ReactDom on refresh

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, web-audio-api, react-scripts

I have the following bug:

I created a new project using CRA with the typescript template:

```
npx create-react-app my-project --template typescript
```

After running `yarn start` everything works fine. But then when I create some new component files, say a `Counter.tsx` and I import it into `App.tsx`, include it in the render/return and then start to make changes to the counter component, nothing shows up anymore on hot reload.
I opened the inspector and the `div#root` is empty after hot reloading.

Only when I change something in the `App.tsx` the React code gets inserted again.

So the behaviour is:

1. Change anything in a child or grandchild etc.. component from `App.tsx`
2. Browser shows empty screen with empty `div#root`

Expected behaviour:

1. Change anything same as before.
2. Browser shows the rendered react including the recent change. (with same state etc..)

Same behaviour tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Am I missing something? The console and browser don't give any error.

Thank you!

EDIT/UPDATE:

This actually only seems to be the case when I include the following context provider that initiates a web audio context:

https://gist.github.com/casperleerink/c10e81f89cf83a282be593ce62c3039d

I tried it using a context that doesn't initiate an audio context, and then everything works fine. Not sure what I should change in my code though.

Comment: Just restart `yarn start` when you add new files , new created files usually throw error before catching up by hot-reload

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly thank you, but this is not the issue, I did some further tests and it seems to be something related to the web audio context. See the updated post